# How can I make this TextView above the FloatingActionButton?

Tags: java, xml, textview

I want to make this textview visible above the FloatinActionButton, but the solutions I've tried didn't work, any other suggestions?
Thank you.

[Android Studio screenshot][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYBWF.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to use `Extended FAB` instead of `FAB`. Ok lets start :

**step 1**

add this to your `build.gradle (moudle)` file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

at the `dependencies`

**step 2**

The `Extended FAB` shape will be rectangle so you should create a drawable resource file and lets call it `shape.xml` and add this code inside it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<size
android:height="50dp"
android:width="50dp"/>
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

**step 3**

Now , lets create the `Extended FAB` and it's will be like this :

```
   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:text="OK"/>
```

---

**the result :**

[image]

Comment: I used ExtendedFloatingActionButton instead of FloatingActionButton and it worked properly, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Just put this inside your textview

```
   android:elevation="1dp"
```

This will give it an elevation.